# EditText to be saved to Integer Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-edittext

I am trying to get numeric user input on an EditText and I want it to be saved to an Integer Arraylist. I have code here that has numbers added programatically to an arraylist called number. I have also added Textviews to display the entire array and the first element of the array to see if it is good.

What I need help with is  the syntax for saving user input into the EditText to the same Arraylist. I have searched this site and found nothing suitable.
I would also like to see the result in the Textview to make sure its working.

```
enter code hereI am trying to get numeric user input on an EditText and I want it to be saved to an Integer Arraylist. I have code here that has numbers added programatically to an arraylist called number. I have also added Textviews to display the entire array and the first element of the array to see if it is good.
```

What I need help with is  the syntax for saving user input into the EditText to the same Arraylist.
I would also like to see the result in the Textview to make sure its working.

```
enter code here  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    look = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    look2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    setUIViews();

    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display1.setText("1");
        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display1.setText("2");
        }
    });

    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display1.setText("3");
        }
    });

    number.add(1);
    number.add(22);
    number.add(45);
    number.add(17);
    number.add(0,7);

    for (int i=0; i < number.size(); i++){
        look2.setText(look2.getText() +" " + number.get(i) + " , ");
        look.setText("First element is: "+number.get(0));
    }

}

private void setUIViews (){

    one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    display1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    display1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    display1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);


}
```

}
    enter code here

```
enter code here<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="244dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="244dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.355" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.416" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="View Arraylist"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.798" />
enter code here
```

Comment: Please post some code showing what are you doing right now and what do you want to achieve. The question which you have asked is easy and needs a simple logic. You can fetch the input from EditText and convert the number to an integer type and then add it to the already created ArrayList.

Comment: How do you want the value from the EditText to be stored in the list? Is there any button that the user must click to do so?

Comment: Just Button 1,or 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

> What I need help with is the syntax for saving user input into the EditText to the same Arraylist.

I think you mean this:

```
number.add(Integer.parseInt(display1.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: @N.Macdonald what message does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

You Can handle EditText.AddonTextChangeListner and cast every 'char' to Int and add it to array and remove in case of deleting i think this will be efficient

Comment: It would be nice to have the number buttons send their corresponding numbers to the array. Preferably directly, if not then indirectly. If onclick wont add to arraylist, then TextChangeListener can get the editText char from my button click as it already stand.